# How to remove the selection indicator(dot) in ng-bootstrap radio buttons

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Here is the example provided by ng bootstrap.
[image: demo]

I cop the same code with only label and value changes into my angular project and get the following result.
[image: my result]

Here's the rendered HTML

```
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle special ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" name="radioBasic" ngbradiogroup="" role="group" ng-reflect-name="radioBasic" ng-reflect-model="user1">
      <label _ngcontent-c1="" class="btn-primary btn active" ngbbuttonlabel="">
        <input _ngcontent-c1="" ngbbutton="" type="radio" value="user1" ng-reflect-value="user1" name="radioBasic">User1
      </label>
      <label _ngcontent-c1="" class="btn-primary btn" ngbbuttonlabel="">
        <input _ngcontent-c1="" ngbbutton="" type="radio" value="user2" ng-reflect-value="user2" name="radioBasic">User2
      </label>

    </div>
```

Why my result is different from the example?
How can I remove the selection dots?

Any fix or pointer to documents will be highly appreciated!

EDIT:

Versions here

Angular CLI: 1.6.1

Angular: 5.1.3

bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6

@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.9

Comment: @Sajeetharan I edited the html directly in the chrome inspect page, but it shows the same result. Btw don't we need to edit the angular src code instead of editing the rendered html?

Comment: if you do not want the user to select you can remove the type completely

Comment: @Sajeetharan I'd like to keep the radio button behavior, just to remove the selection dot for better appearance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.9` is not fully compatible with `bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6`.

As bootstrap 4 beta 3 evolve and change the radio and checkbox system, ng-bootstrap don't work anymore with previous version for that.

Best solution is to jump to a `bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3`.

If you can't, you should keep `ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.8`.

Comment: I have the same issue with `bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3` and `ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.9`

Answer (score 1):

> Why my result is different from the example?

I think the reason for this behaviour is due to conflict between [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) and [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home).

You might be using both of them on the same page, and when the Bootstrap library sees an `input` element of the type 'radio', it is generating those selection dots.

> How can I remove the selection dots?

Acess that radio `input` element using any CSS selector, and then change its `display` property to `none`, like:

```
input {
  display: none;
}
```

This will remove those selection dots from the page.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to `bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3` to use `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.9`.

---

If you are locked to `bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2` (angular-cli [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9020)) you can downgrade to `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.8`. But note that live ng-bootstrap docs show the latest version and `btn-group-toggle` class was previously unnecessary [1.0.0-beta.8](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/1.0.0-beta.8/demo/src/app/components/buttons/demos/radio/buttons-radio.html).

Working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap)

Comment: bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3 breaks angular CLI then I tried beta 2, the issue persists

Comment: The radio button changes were in [bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta.3) so beta.2 won't work. What do you mean it "breaks angular CLI"?

Comment: @hayden breaks angular CLI means if I include bootstrap beta 3, angular cli fails to build the project. The issue is discussed here [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9020)